# Как исключить строку из массива, для последующего поиска min значения?

Tags: java

Есть массив стрингов со значениями:

```
480.00
490.00
1.00
244.95
434.99
0.00 - 1.00
590.99
1.00
260.00
0.01
22.99
19.99
```

Как исключить строку со значением "0.00 - 1.00"?
Смысл в том, что нужно найти минимальное значение.Спасибо заранее))

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понимаю, вы хотите удалить элемент массива. Если вы знаете позицию этого элемента, вы можете занулить его и сдвинуть все последующие элементы массива влево. Далее пройдитесь по массиву с размером текущего, но на один меньший.

Чтобы получить из **String** значение типа **double**, можете воспользоваться следующим кодом:

```
String s = "480.00";
double x = Double.parseDouble(s);
```

Comment: Как поступить в случае если не известна позиция элемента, и строк с значениями "0.00 - 1.00" несколько?

Comment: Позицию первого появление элемента в массиве можно найти таким способом `int position = Arrays.asList(array).indexOf("0.00 - 1.00")`, далее, зная эту позицию, можете "удалить" элемент. После снова воспользуетесь тем же кодом для нахождения следующего появления строки. Если элемент не будет найдет, метод `indexOf()` вернёт -1. Естественно все это можно организовать в виде цикла.

Comment: Или если проще, то можно просто пройти по массиву циклом